# Accidentally deleted Line breakpoints from Intellij Idea debugger setting.

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I accidentally deleted the "Line Debugger" from the Idea debugger setting window (Ctrl +Shift + F8). I cannot get it back. Is there a way to reset the setting ? or to add it back.

Comment: What do you mean by "Line Debugger" ? Do you mean you deleted a `Java Line Breakpoint` ?

Comment: You have to just add a new breakpoint by clicking in the margin next to the line you want the debugger to stop on.

Comment: I am afraid the problem is way more sinister. I deleted the "Line breakpoint" class and was not able to add it back. Since I deleted it, I was not able to add any more line breakpoints (only method and Exception breakpoints). I had to reinstall Idea.

Comment: How did you delete the "Line breaskpoint" class?

Comment: Unfortunately it was very easy to do that. From the debugger setting UI, I highlighted "Line Debugger" and pressed "-". I thought this would just clear out all the "Line breakpoints", instead it removed the whole class.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same problem as you do. When I try to toggle a breakpoint by clicking with a mouse I get the following stack trace in `~/.IdeaIC15/system/log/idea.log`.

```
2015-12-14 16:07:42,111 [ 237626]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2  Build #IC-143.1184.17 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,112 [ 237627]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - JDK: 1.8.0_66 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,112 [ 237627]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,112 [ 237627]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,112 [ 237627]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Linux 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,112 [ 237627]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Last Action: ToggleLineBreakpoint 
2015-12-14 16:07:42,716 [ 238231]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - com.intellij.ide.scratch.ScratchFileType.getOriginalFileType(Lcom/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/fileTypes/FileT
ype; 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.scratch.ScratchFileType.getOriginalFileType(Lcom/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/fileTypes/FileType;
        at com.jetbrains.python.debugger.PyLineBreakpointType.isPythonScratch(PyLineBreakpointType.java:72)
        at com.jetbrains.python.debugger.PyLineBreakpointType.canPutAt(PyLineBreakpointType.java:49)
        at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.breakpoints.XBreakpointUtil.toggleLineBreakpoint(XBreakpointUtil.java:166)
        at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.breakpoints.XLineBreakpointManager$MyEditorMouseListener$1$1.run(XLineBreakpointManager.java:304)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:337)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:321)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Searching with that error on the Jetbrains bug tracker, I found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149265. As suggested there, disabling the Python plugin solved the issue for me.